# Financial Year in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to select data of financial year

I'm using the below query but not working

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_column ,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 
CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1,'-04-01') AND CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE),'-03-31')
```

can anyone help!

Comment: That query works perfect for me (of course changing out the `TABLE` and `date_column` items)

Running against a MySQL 5.6 database with the `date_column` being a type of `DATETIME`

What is the error/problem that you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Working. I wanted to get current fiscal year.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_column ,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN
CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-0,'-04-01') AND CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+1,'-03-31')
```

Comment: You don't need to add the `-0` in the `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-0` to get the current date, you just need to use `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)`. Because the `-0` is unnecessary and has no effect.

Comment: Your condition is not SAGRable and causes complete table scan instead of index usage. What is thу reason to use STR_TO_DATE? it looks like excess. Moreover, the whole expression performs string, not date, comparing. And your query will produce wrong output in Jan..Mar.